# How do I create a copy of this class and then use it's functions inside XNA (Gamedrawable Component)

Tags: xna, renderer

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace TileEngine
{
    class Renderer : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

         public Renderer(Game game)
            : base(game)
        {
            // TODO: Construct any child components here
        }







        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
           // base.LoadContent();
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {



            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }


        public RenderTarget2D new_texture(int width, int height)
        {
            Texture2D TEX = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);   //create the texture to render to
            RenderTarget2D Mine = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Mine); //set the render device to the reference provided
            //maybe base.draw can be used with spritebatch. Idk. We'll see if the order of operation
            //works out. Wish I could call base.draw here.
            return Mine;    //I'm hoping that this returns the same instance and not a copy.

        }

        public void draw_texture(int width, int height, RenderTarget2D Mine)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); //Set the renderer to render to the backbuffer again
            Rectangle drawrect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height); //Set the rendering size to what we want
            spriteBatch.Begin();                        //This uses spritebatch to draw the texture directly to the screen  
            spriteBatch.Draw(Mine, drawrect, Color.White); //This uses the color white
            spriteBatch.End();      //ends the spritebatch
            //Call base.draw after this since it doesn't seem to recognize inside the function
            //maybe base.draw can be used with spritebatch. Idk. We'll see if the order of operation
            //works out. Wish I could call base.draw here.
        }



        public GraphicsDevice myDevice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I still can't call this class as an object in XNA

Here is the working code in the initialize function where I try to create it.
But in my draw code it still doesn't let me go:

```
tileclipping.draw_texture(...);
```

Here's the full code from game1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using TileEngine;

namespace TileEngine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {

        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


        TileMap myMap = new TileMap();
        int squaresAcross = 12;
        int squaresDown = 12;

        public Game1()
        {
             graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {

           // tileClipping = new Renderer(); 
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            Renderer tileclipping = new Renderer(this) ;
            //Components.Add(tileclippping);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            Tile.TileSetTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\TileSets\part1_tileset");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                Camera.Location.X = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.X - 8, 0, (myMap.MapWidth - squaresAcross) * 32);
            }

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            {
                Camera.Location.X = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.X + 8, 0, (myMap.MapWidth - squaresAcross) * 32);
            }

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                Camera.Location.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.Y - 8, 0, (myMap.MapHeight - squaresDown) * 32);
            }

            if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                Camera.Location.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(Camera.Location.Y + 8, 0, (myMap.MapHeight - squaresDown) * 32);
            }
            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            //use the instance of renderer called tileclipping to generate a new texture of a specified size for tiles
            //this surface is 200 pixels by 200 pixels for the reason that it's the same as the clipping i'll choose



            Texture2D mytexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 200, 200);
            RenderTarget2D Mine = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, 200, 200);
            //Mine = tileclipping.new_texture(200, 200);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            Vector2 firstSquare = new Vector2(Camera.Location.X / 32, Camera.Location.Y / 32);
            int firstX = (int)firstSquare.X;
            int firstY = (int)firstSquare.Y;

            Vector2 squareOffset = new Vector2(Camera.Location.X % 32, Camera.Location.Y % 32);            
            int offsetX = (int)squareOffset.X;
            int offsetY = (int)squareOffset.Y;

            for (int y = 0; y < squaresDown; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < squaresAcross; x++)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(
                        Tile.TileSetTexture,
                        new Rectangle((x * 32) - offsetX, (y * 32) - offsetY, 32, 32),
                        Tile.GetSourceRectangle(myMap.Rows[y + firstY].Columns[x + firstX].TileID),
                        Color.White);
                }
            }

            spriteBatch.End();
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            //There are two instances of mine
                //A new one is made each time tileclipping.new_texture is called
                    //This function can re use the copy created by new texture
                        //hopefully this saves on memory







            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public CubeMapFace Tex2d { get; set; }

        internal Renderer tileClipping { get; set; }

        public IGameComponent tileclippping { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if it isn't clear what i'm trying to do.
I'm trying to capture a 2d texture (or create one) OUTSIDE my game class
I'm trying to use a class as a handler, to pass these texture2d's back and forth between GAME1
and my Renderer
I don't WANT to have all my textures inside my main class.
Also another thing with this is that I'm trying to basically have a generic
texture2d CREATOR.

Aka this isn't for something simple like rendering sprites.
The function of RENDERER is to either create a new TEXTURE2D object with a NEW render target object
based on parameters fed to this function:

```
public RenderTarget2D new_texture(int width, int height)
        {
            Texture2D TEX = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);   //create the texture to render to
            RenderTarget2D Mine = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Mine); //set the render device to the reference provided
            //maybe base.draw can be used with spritebatch. Idk. We'll see if the order of operation
            //works out. Wish I could call base.draw here.
            return Mine;    //I'm hoping that this returns the same instance and not a copy.

        }
```

I need a way of creating a copy of the renderer class WITHOUT having it in the gamecomponents list.
The reason is because XNA won't let me access Graphics device, which is a required parameter OF a texture2D object.
So basically i'm doing all this stuff as a work around just becuase Texture2D requires graphics device as a parameter and I can't willy nilly pass GraphicsDevice INTO an instance of my renderer class i've already tried that and it fails.

So there will be situations in my game where say

```
if (Camera_zoom==1){
scaling_texture.dispose();
scaling_texture = tileclipping.new_texture(camera_width*camera_zoom, camera_height*camera_zoom);

// call a refresh command here

this.refresh_scene(...) //Inside here is a ton of sprite batches because the render target is now set to NEW scaling_texture

//after that we do the drawing using spritebatch inside draw function of main game class
//expecting that a render texture is provided for us by these pre requisites.
//then after that we call the render command
//it returns the render target to the screen

//then in the draw command AFTER the sprite batches were drawn TO the target surface called scaling_texture
//We use various parameters to tell it to draw this scaling_texture as a spritebatch.draw() inside the 
//game1 draw class
//So basically I want to do things in this order
/// Create new texture of variable size
// use it as render target
// Do all my spritebatch
// call another spritebatch
//draw the contents of said texture on the screen as the rendering target
//Dispose of the texture object
//Check the scaling size of it
//Re create the scaling texture with a NEW resolution (each frame)
//Select it as a render target
//Do the spritebatchy stuff all over again repeat above for all game loop
//BUT I want parts of this, mainly the creation of this Texture2D object, and the drawing of it to the backbuffer
//To all happen inside my Renderer class
//but for all main game spritebatches to happen inside my main game class
//This is a problem for me and XNA doesn't seem to want to let me organize it this way
//Unless i'm missing something which is why i'm making this lengthy post
//ANY and all help is appreciated.
//Thanks again and I hope I explained myself well enough this time IE my intentions.
//PLEASE NOTE I am SET on doing things THIS way. I will NEED a texture 2d rendering target that is NON static
//During MOST of my GAME project.
//That said.. IT HAS TO have function to wrap it inside Renderer. THere is no way in hell I'm going to do this
//In a spaghetti code fashion Inside GAME1 with nested if statements. 
//Thanks all
```

}

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you are trying to create your own texture2d object, either its WAY more advance than what I'm used too ... or something you shouldnt.  Maybe check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642746/best-way-to-handle-texture-loading-and-access-across-multiple-classes-in-xna

Comment: That link was somewhat informative, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just took the time to read it completely, and if I understand correctly, you want to have all your textures into a manager to be able to acess them from everywhere in your program ?

what I normally do is have a Class like this one :

```
Class Images
{

  public static Texture2d Ball;
  public static Texture2d Hero;

  public static void loadContent(Content content)
  {
    Ball = content.load<Texture2d>("/GFX/GameObject/Ball");
    Hero = content.load<Texture2d>("/GFX/SpriteSheet/Hero");
  }
}
```

This class allow you to use Image.Hero or Image.Ball from everywhere in your code. All you have to do is to set it in your game loadcontent sub :

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Images.LoadContent(GraphicsDeviceManager.Content);
        Sounds.LoadContent(GraphicsDeviceManager.Content);
        Tile.TileSetTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\TileSets\part1_tileset");

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }
```

From here, if you need to recreate or reload the texture in your own renderer class, you could set images.ball getter or setter differently and handle it how you want, or just create a new function to clone these texture and do what you need for your renderer class.    Edit : I'm not 100% sure about if the class itself is static or not, I dont have the code in front of me and I didnt touch it in a long time.

---

I'm not home, so I cant find the tutorial I had about splash screen. but it also let you load a delegate instead of an asset, and that delegate lets you do some actions instead : as the 1st item to load, you load all the texture and fonts needed for your splash screen, as well as a background music that you start playing right away. If you want, let me know and I'll add in the link once I get home.